# How to exclude bean validation module from war deployment in Wildfly 10.0?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, classloader, wildfly

I have an application which is deployed as a `.war` in `Wildfly 10.0`. My application uses `hibernate-validator-4.2.0` which implements [Bean Validation Specification 1.0](http://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/). Wildfly uses hibernate-validator-5.2.3 which implements [Bean Validation Specification 1.1](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/).  Obviously, this causes conflicts. If I exclude `hibernate-validator-5.2.3` the app fails if I exlude `hibernate-validator-4.2.0` Widlfy won't start.

The Official Wildfly Documentation is silent about Bean Validation (cannot post a third link yet).

And yes, I know about the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. I have tried to exclude the hibernate validator shipped with `Wildfly 10.0` :

```
<exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main"/>
</exclusions>
```

from a `<deployment>` or a `<sub-deployment>` as well, but then Wildfly would not start corerctly (org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidationExtension would not load because `hibernate-validator-4.2.3` does not have the `ConfigurationImpl.getBootstrapConfiguration()` method required by the extension).

Is there a way to exclude the `hibernate-validator-5.2.3` only from my application **when that is deployed as a `.war` file**?

Comment: I think it will be easier for you to upgrade to use the 1,1 spec to be honest with you. If you're going to use an app server that conforms to a spec you should entertain it.
If you want to downgrade you're going to have to do a lot more work than just replacing that one jar - you're going to need to check the module.xml file for hibernate validator in the modules directory - and check all the dependencies and their versions and compare them to the dependencies of the old version and keep following the module.xml trail until you've replaced all the dependencies.

Comment: @Miles: the thing is if we upgrade hibernate-validator, we have to upgrade hibernate as well, which I don't know how much would cost. That's why I#d likw to knwo whether its possible to exclude the jars only from the application classpath?

Comment: The issue is that Wildfly uses it's own implementations of some of the Hibernate modules - If you check org/hibernate you will see a couple jboss jars, now I'm not 100% sure if that will interfere with replacing just the validator - you'd have to mess around, sorry I haven't done this before myself... Hope someone else stumbles across this :)